# How can I replace completely one of nodes with new data within fragment xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I am a new user on this forum and I'm not a highly experienced developer/programmer.  Before asking this question, I searched and looked through Stack Overflow and some Microsoft suggested links, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

I've got the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<WndPos name="FrontEnd.Login" l="703" r="1264" t="323" b="909" />
<LayerManager />
<ViewLayers name="RoofLayout" roof="1" nlwalls="1">
    <Layer level="-1" module="1" name="Walls" locked="0" visible="1" />
</ViewLayers>
<DirProfiles>
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="ControlCQFT" JobPath="C:\Jobs" DatabasePath="D:\Database\ControlCQFT" />
</DirProfiles>
<DirHistory>
     <ProfileInfo Use="Job" Path="C:\Jobs" />
</DirHistory>
```

I need to replace the entire `<DirProfiles>` node. The incoming node can be empty, which looks like `<DirProfiles />`. The new node that I want to insert is in the format:

```
<DirProfiles> 
      <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control1" JobPath="D:\Client1\JobsA" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control1" />
. . . . .
</DirProfiles>
```

I tried to handle the problem as a simple string replacement, but I didn't get the result that I needed.

**Edit:**
My apology, I didn't realized that my xml file is fragment xml document and not full XML as per spec.

Comment: Why didn't string replace work for you?

Comment: Never use string methods on an XML.  The xml libraries in Net are much better!!! The old xml does not have "DirProfile" only "DriProfiles".  I would recommend using Xml Linq library in Net.  There isn't enough info in posting for me to give an example code.

Comment: @jdweng My apology, I made small typo. Yes I mean that I have to overwrite `<DirProfiles />` node. What additional data you need to give an example code?

Comment: @Felix - The "XML" you've provided isn't XML. There's no root node. Can you please fix it?

Comment: @Enigmativity I provided exact structure of xml file we got in our application that I am testing. Yes, probably this is not correct xml structure as it should be, but nevertheless it is what I have deal with.

Comment: @Felix - It's not XML though, according to the XML spec. You'd need to do add a root node to make it parse-able. I'd check your file though, the XML header is usually automatically added. I think your original file might be correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are correct, I don't have full XML file. What I got is: "_A document fragment is an XML file that doesn’t have a root element_". So I have to read this document fragment file before I can do anything with It.

Comment: @Felix - You should state that in your question rather than calling it an XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input file is a malformed XML file that doesn't contain a root node, you can get around this with a bit of string manipulation.

Here's the file you say you have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<WndPos name="FrontEnd.Login" l="703" r="1264" t="323" b="909" />
<LayerManager />
<ViewLayers name="RoofLayout" roof="1" nlwalls="1">
    <Layer level="-1" module="1" name="Walls" locked="0" visible="1" />
</ViewLayers>
<DirProfiles>
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="ControlCQFT" JobPath="C:\Jobs" DatabasePath="D:\Database\ControlCQFT" />
</DirProfiles>
<DirHistory>
     <ProfileInfo Use="Job" Path="C:\Jobs" />
</DirHistory>
```

Here's how to work with it:

```
var sourceFileName = @"C:\{path}\xml_fragments.txt";

var text = $"<root>{String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(sourceFileName).Skip(1))}</root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(text);

doc.Root.Element("DirProfiles").Elements().Remove();

doc.Root.Element("DirProfiles").Add(
    new XElement(
        "ProfileInfo",
        new XAttribute("ProfileName", "Control1"),
        new XAttribute("JobPath", @"D:\Client1\JobsA"),
        new XAttribute("DatabasePath", @"D:\Database\Control1")));
```

That gives me:

```
<root>
  <WndPos name="FrontEnd.Login" l="703" r="1264" t="323" b="909" />
  <LayerManager />
  <ViewLayers name="RoofLayout" roof="1" nlwalls="1">
    <Layer level="-1" module="1" name="Walls" locked="0" visible="1" />
  </ViewLayers>
  <DirProfiles>
    <ProfileInfo ProfileName="Control1" JobPath="D:\Client1\JobsA" DatabasePath="D:\Database\Control1" />
  </DirProfiles>
  <DirHistory>
    <ProfileInfo Use="Job" Path="C:\Jobs" />
  </DirHistory>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for code example. I tried it, but got error: _There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 2._ I'll think how I can avoid it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XElement doc = new XElement("Root");
            doc.Add(XElement.Parse(xml));

            XElement dirProfiles = doc.Descendants("DirProfiles").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement profileInfo = dirProfiles.Element("ProfileInfo");
            profileInfo.SetAttributeValue("ProfileName", "Control1");
            profileInfo.SetAttributeValue("JobPath", @"D:\Client1\JobsA");
            profileInfo.SetAttributeValue("DatabasePath", @"D:\Database\Control1");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code example. I have to load my xml file in another way due to the fact that I got fragment xml document and not full XML file.

Comment: I modified the code to wrap the xml array with a single <Root></Root> tag to solve the array issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the XML data to a C# class model, and after that could do the data changes as per requirement. After changes, you can again parse the model object to XML and rewrite the XML string on the same file.

Refer this link for generate a class structure by available XML: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-xml-json-file-to-c-sharp-class

And Use this code to Convert Xml to a C# class object

```
public static T ConvertXmlToObject<T>(String xml)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                try
                {
                    result =
                        (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // Throw message for invalid XML
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Call the function like :

```
var entity = ConvertXmlToObject<ModelClass>(XMLString);
```

User this code to convert again Object to XML

```
public static string ConvertObjectToXML<T>(T ModelClass)
        {
            XmlSerializer xsObject = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var inputObject = ModelClass;
            var xmlString = "";

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
                {
                    xsObject.Serialize(writer, inputObject);
                    xmlString = sw.ToString();
                }
            }

            return xmlString;
        }
```

Call this function like :

```
string xmlString = ConvertObjectToXML<ModelClass>(ModelClassObject);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posing an answer links are OK but it is better to put code snippets.

Comment: @Arun Sugandhi Thank you for reply. I would agree with Edney, some code example will be highly appreciated. I don't have to change data, I need completely replace it with new data, overwrite it if you like.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying the XML Node will be different.
If you know about all the possible nodes, so you can generate all the classes for corresponding, and set the object null which you don't want then proceed.

Comment: @EdneyHolder - No, links are not OK - UNLESS they are there to support content you have already put in the answer. It is not "better to put in code snippets". You must put in full content before posting links.